# NAudio Start new song error

Tags: c#, naudio

I'm trying to develop a music player based on NAudio lib. When I first start a song, its OK. When I try to start another song, I get an error:

> InvalidParameter calling waveOutOpen at string:

```
player.Init(aReader);
```

A little context: I'm using those methods to start and stop playing a song:

**Playing**

```
        StopAudio();
        aReader = new AudioFileReader((string)musicFile);
        aReader.Volume = Form1.Singleton.GetMusicVolume();

        player.Init(aReader);
        player.Play();
```

**Re-Playing / Stopping**

```
       if (player == null || aReader == null) return;

        aReader.Dispose();
        player.Stop();
        player.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.
At song stopping needs to make player & nAudio as null, and at start check is player null and if it is then initialize it.